# Redirect url with language variable to different url htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to make the following redirection using htaccess (WordPress)

```
http://oldweb.com/pl/
```

to `https://newweb.com/url/differenturl/`

But this redirection should work only for `http://oldweb.com/pl/`, the urls `http://oldweb.com/en/` or `http://oldweb.com/il/` should not have any redirection.

My solution works but it works for /en/ and /il/ also:

```
Redirect 301 http://oldweb.com/pl/ https://newweb.com/url/differenturl/
```

I'm not a hero in rewriting, sorry :) Can anyone help me with this simple thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` matches only `REQUEST_URI` not full URL with domain protocol etc.

Better to use a `RewriteRule` just below `RewriteEngine On` line in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?oldweb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^pl/?$ https://newweb.com/url/differenturl/ [L,NC,R=301]
```